Passing bash array as options into executable command
I have this simplified command, executed in a .bashrc function:
aws sso login --profile myprofile --cli-read-timeout 5

I'm trying to replace the command options with an array of options:
params=('--profile myprofile')
params+=('--cli-read-timeout 5')
aws sso login "${params[*]}"

AWS complains about unknown options:
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --profile myprofile --cli-read-timeout 5

What is the correct format to be used in order to properly execute the command?

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

The option name and its argument must be separate array elements.
params=('--profile' 'myprofile')
params+=('--cli-read-timeout' '5')
aws sso login "${params[@]}"

or you can use --option=value syntax:
params=('--profile=myprofile')
params+=('--cli-read-timeout=5')
aws sso login "${params[@]}"

Also, you must use ${params[@]} rather than ${params[*]} so that each array element will be expanded to a separate word.
Your code is equivalent to combining all the parameters into a single argument:
aws sso login '--profile myprofile --cli-read-timeout 5'


Thank you for the useful information @Barmar, is it recommended to declare the array with declare -a params=('--profile' 'myprofile')?

@Floren Using declare -a is optional. Bash can difure out that it's an array from the ( right after the = in the assignment. If the parameters don't contain any special characters (e.g. spaces), you can omit the quotes around them when setting the array. The simple rule is that when setting the array, you can quote (or not quote) the same way you would when using those arguments directly as part of the command.

@Floren See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444686/understanding-the-point-of-declaring-an-array-in-bash for the benefits of declaring the array.
